# Grails: How to change the default validation error messages to other languages?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to change the default validation messages to other languages like French, Japanese or Chinese but there's only one default language(English) I can see in my project(I'm using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.6.0).

The fastest way to solve this question is to overwrite the default validation messages file(messages.properties) with other one such as messages_ja.properties.

I'm just wondering if there is another "dynamic" way to achieve this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change default langugage you can define something like this in your conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
beans = { 
  localeResolver(SessionLocaleResolver) { 
        defaultLocale= Locale.JAPAN
        Locale.setDefault (Locale.JAPAN) 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your application as a different default language from English then the best approach is:

1. Rename messages.properties to messages_en.properties
2. Rename the messages_xx.properties to messages.properties (where xx is the new default)

This way English is still available for your application should you need to support it as well as your new default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been trying to simply change the file names but I don't know why those messages still showing in English.